# why my snake, water, gun game is not working properly?

Tags: javascript

I am building the snake, water, gun game in js; everything is fine from my point of view but it's not working properly. I use math.random method so, it can choose one of the snake, water and gun game. then, It will check who wins. at last, It will decide who will be the final winner.

```
let words = ['Snake', 'Water', 'Gun'];
let random = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
let input;
let user_points = 0;
let computer_points = 0;
let chances = 0;
do {
  input = prompt("Enter any one (snake, water, gun) =");
  if (input == random) {
    console.log("Draw");
    chances++
  }
  else if (input == 'snake' && random == 'gun') {
    console.log("Computer wins!");
    chances++
    computer_points++
  }
  else if (input == 'snake' && random == 'water') {
    console.log("You wins!");
    chances++
    user_points++
  }
  else if (input == 'water' && random == 'snake') {
    console.log("Computer wins!");
    chances++
    computer_points++
  }
  else if (input == 'water' && random == 'gun') {
    console.log("You wins!");
    chances++
    user_points++
  }
  else if (input == 'gun' && random == 'water') {
    console.log("Computer wins!");
    chances++
    computer_points++
  }
  else if (input == 'gun' && random == 'snake') {
    console.log("You wins!");
    chances++
    user_points++
  }
  else {
    console.log('this not a valid input');
  }
} while (chances <= 5);
console.log(`Your points = ${user_points}`);
console.log(`Computer points = ${computer_points}`);
if (user_points < computer_points) {
  console.log('Sorry, but the finall winner is computer.');
  console.log('Game ended');
}
else if (user_points > computer_points) {
  console.log('Congrats!, You are the Finall winner.');
  console.log('Game ended');
}
else {
  console.log("The game is end and It's a draw.");
}
```

code link- [click here to view code](https://replit.com/@vishal30982/Snake-Water-Gun-game#index.js)

Comment: How exactly is it not working properly? What's the expected result vs actual result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I Thanks you All For The suggestions !**

But I found the solution now 
Corrected code :-

```
let words = ['snake', 'water', 'gun'];
let random = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
let input;
let user_points = 0;
let computer_points = 0;
let chances = 0;
do {
  input = prompt("Enter any one (snake, water, gun) =").trim().toLowerCase();
  if (input == random) {
    console.log("Draw");
    chances++
    random = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  }
  else if (input == 'snake' && random == 'gun') {
    console.log("Computer wins!");
    chances++
    computer_points++
    random = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  }
  else if (input == 'snake' && random == 'water') {
    console.log("You wins!");
    chances++
    user_points++
    random = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  }
  else if (input == 'water' && random == 'snake') {
    console.log("Computer wins!");
    chances++
    computer_points++
    random = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  }
  else if (input == 'water' && random == 'gun') {
    console.log("You wins!");
    chances++
    user_points++
    
  }
  else if (input == 'gun' && random == 'water') {
    console.log("Computer wins!");
    chances++
    computer_points++
  }
  else if (input == 'gun' && random == 'snake') {
    console.log("You wins!");
    chances++
    user_points++
  }
  else {
    console.log('this not a valid input');
  }
} while (chances < 5);
console.log(`Your points = ${user_points}`);
console.log(`Computer points = ${computer_points}`);
if (user_points < computer_points) {
  console.log('Sorry, but the final winner is computer.');
  console.log('Game ended');
}
else if (user_points > computer_points) {
  console.log('Congrats!, You are the Final winner.');
  console.log('Game ended');
}
else {
  console.log("The game is end and It's a draw.");
}
```

Code Link :- [Click To View Code](https://replit.com/@vishal30982/Snake-Water-Gun-game)

Answer (score 0):

you just have to make the alphabets small in line no 1 i.e,
let words = ['snake', 'water', 'gun']

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).